# Lookup in column and line

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table in google sheet of this type :

first column with IDs, then in the first line there is dates

| IDs   | 01/04/2023 | 02/04/2023 | 03/04/2023 | 04/04/2023 |

| ID1   | Cell 2     | Cell 2     | Cell 2     | Cell 2     |

| ID2   | Cell 4     | Cell 4     | Cell 4     | Cell 4     |

| ID3   | Cell 2     | Cell 2     | Cell 2     | Cell 2     |

| ID4   | Cell 4     | Cell 4     | Cell 4     | Cell 4     |

thank you

so i want to lookup a data when an ID and a date match and if it's possible to use arrayformula to lookup with varios id and one or 2 dates it's gonna be perfect if it's possible, if it's not, one id and one date can be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the INDEX and MATCH functions together to lookup data based on both ID and date. Here is an example formula to lookup data for a single ID and date:

```
=INDEX(A2:E5, MATCH("ID1", A2:A5, 0), MATCH("01/04/2023", A1:E1, 0))
```